Sankey Diagram Label Positioning with Python, Dash
Since the plotly library does not support any in-built functionality to change the label positioning. I tried the solution in the post :
How to Specify Node Label Position for Sankey Diagram in Plotly
Using this example, it works with simple plotly figure objects but I am not able to make it work with dash. I don't get any runtime error but i don't get the desired result .i.e labels in center of the node. Below is the code.
from plotly import graph_objects as go
import plotly
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

js = '''
const TEXTPAD = 3; // constant used in Plotly.js

function sankeyNodeLabelsAlign(position, forcePos) {
  const textAnchor = {left: 'end', right: 'start', center: 'middle'}[position];
  const nodes = gd.getElementsByClassName('sankey-node');

  for (const node of nodes) {
    const d = node.__data__;
    const label = node.getElementsByClassName('node-label').item(0);

    // Ensure to reset any previous modifications
    label.setAttribute('x', 0);

    if (!d.horizontal)
      continue;

    // This is how Plotly's default text positioning is computed (coordinates
    // are relative to that of the cooresponding node).
    const padX = d.nodeLineWidth / 2 + TEXTPAD;
    const posX = padX + d.visibleWidth;
    let x;

    switch (position) {
      case 'left':
        if (d.left || d.node.originalLayer === 0 && !forcePos)
          continue;
        x = -posX - padX;
        break;

      case 'right':
        if (!d.left || !forcePos)
          continue;
        x = posX + padX;
        break;

      case 'center':
        if (!forcePos && (d.left || d.node.originalLayer === 0))
          continue;
        x = (d.nodeLineWidth + d.visibleWidth)/2 + (d.left ? padX : -posX);
        break;
    }

    label.setAttribute('x', x);
    label.setAttribute('text-anchor', textAnchor);
  }
}


const gd = document.getElementById('{plot_id}');
const position = 'center';
const forcePos = true;

gd.on('plotly_afterplot', sankeyNodeLabelsAlign.bind(gd, position, forcePos));
gd.emit('plotly_afterplot'); // manual trigger for initial rendering
'''

source = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
target = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1]
value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2, 8]
labels = ["ABCDEFG", "BCDEFG", "CDEFG", "DEFG", "EFG"]

# Create the Sankey diagram
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node={
        "label": labels,
        "color": "blue",
        "pad": 15,
        "thickness": 20,
        "line": {"color": "black", "width": 0.5},
    },
    link={
        "source": source,
        "target": target,
        "value": value
    })])
# fig.show(post_script=[js], visible=False)


app = dash.Dash(__name__)  # , external_scripts=["./java.js"])
# Layout of the Dash app
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='sankey-diagram',
        figure=fig,
        config={'displayModeBar': False}
    ),
    html.Script(js.replace('{plot_id}', 'sankey-diagram'))
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)


